# Why do I get rat error while regarding two unapproved license while installing Ambari 2.7.5?

Tags: maven, ambari

I am trying to install ambari 2.7.5 on centos 7. I am following the instructions given on this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5). When I run the mvn install commad as mentioned in the link. It fails with a rat error that 2 unapproved licenses were found. I downloaded the ambari source from apache site. Then how come I did not get proper license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VK Here is the full command you need to skip the drat checks:

```
mvn -Drat.skip=true -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.7"
```

and here is the skip drat argument:

```
-Drat.skip=true
```

If you attempt to build a clean install multiple times with failures you will hit the drat license limit and it will require the drat skip.   One way to avoid is to follow the maven suggestion to resume the build from the last failure.

```
mvn <args> -rf [Failed Step]
```